# How do I replace a substring in java without using the replace method and if the function has multiple parameters?

Tags: java

I'm writing a function that will return a string with all instances of a substring replaced with a smaller substring. For example, if the user enters the string "aabaacaaa", enters "aa" for the word, and enters "a" for the letter it should return "abacaa". Mine just returns "aabaacaaa".

The problem is that I haven't found a way to replace a string, without using the replace method, when the function has more than 2 parameters. All the examples I've seen always have either one or two parameters and never more. Here's the code I have now.

```
    public static String replaceWordWithLetter(String str, String word, String c)
    {
        //This method will return 'str' with all instances of 'word' replaced by letter 'c'.
        
        String result = "";
        
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
          if(str.substring(i, i+1).equals(word))
          {
            if(word.substring(i, i+1).equals(c))
            {
              word = c;
              result = result + word;
            }
          }
          else{
            result += str.substring(i,i+1);
          }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with those nested if statements?

Comment: What is the purpose of `if(word.substring(i, i+1).equals(c))`?

Comment: @sotirios I was trying to see if what I did with my other two replace functions could work for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use the `String.index` method. Note that this solution will take a string larger than a letter.  And it is case sensitive.

```
String ss = replaceWordWithLetter("aabaacaaa", "aa","a");
System.out.println(ss);
```

Prints

```
abacaa
```

- get the index of the word in the string.
- append everything up to that to the current result
- append your replacement string.
- replace the original string with the string after the location of the word (i.e word + wlength).  So the original string now begins just after the word that was found.
- continue until the word to be replaced is no longer found (indexOf returns -1).

```
public static String replaceWordWithLetter(String str, String word, String c) {
     String result = "";
     int idx = 0;
     int wlength = word.length();
     while ((idx = str.indexOf(word)) >= 0) {
        result += str.substring(0, idx)+c;
        str = str.substring(idx+wlength);
     }
     return result+str;
 }
```

Comment: What does the "save" part mean? And indexOf

Comment: My apologies.  That is what is known as "residual garbage", left over by the operator (aka me).  I have corrected the post.